# Jenkins pipeline npm install EACSS permission denied

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, npm-install

I got this error when I trying to run "npm install" through jenkins pipeline on one of my jenkins slave.But I can install successfully by run this command directly on that slave node.
This is the error Msg I got:

```
14:10:11  > node-sass@4.13.0 install /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass
14:10:11  > node scripts/install.js
14:10:11  
14:10:11  Unable to save binary /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72 : Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
14:10:11      at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:823:3)
14:10:11      at sync (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
14:10:11      at Function.sync (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
14:10:11      at checkAndDownloadBinary (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
14:10:11      at Object.<anonymous> (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
14:10:11      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
14:10:11      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
14:10:11      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
14:10:11      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
14:10:11      at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
14:10:11    errno: -13,
14:10:11    syscall: 'mkdir',
14:10:11    code: 'EACCES',
14:10:11    path: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsBuild/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
14:10:11  }
```

so How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

can you send your code ?

If it's help, personally I usually do the following (scripted syntax)
(you need to install the nodejs plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)

checkout my repo on folder "Build", and then :

```
    stage ("build") { 
         dir('Build') {
            env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'Node 12.12'}"
            env.PATH="${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'npm run someScript'
            sh 'npm pack'  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi , I checked some document and fond out that seems I got this error due to some kind of cache problem, and I got it fixed simply by setting the prefix to another folder... anyway thanks for your answer